# How to fix "Bad interpreter" error when using yum?

Tags: python, yum

```
$ yum install httpd-devel
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a file called `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/yum` ?  if either of them is missing, you could create a soft link to the executable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first line of any bash, Perl, or Python script tells bash where to find the correct interpreter.  For yum it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

You can tell where Python is actually installed by typing:

```
which python
```

The best way to fix this is to add a symbolic link.  For example:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python /usr/bin/python
```

That way you don't have to fix it in every script.