# pip install scrapy but it's bad

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to install Scrapy like this

```
pip install scrapy
```

However I'm getting

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How can I get fix this?

Comment: What is your OS? Do you have bash or any other shell? Do you have python installed?

Comment: My os is OSX python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you do not have a python interpreter installed or may have it in a non-standard location.

Similar issue with YUM:
[How to fix "Bad interpreter" error when using yum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421399/how-to-fix-bad-interpreter-error-when-using-yum)

Comment: I tray it but ln: /usr/bin/python: Permission denied